# <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

when I transfer my project from one system to another for work , I got error  " file not found" 
then I remove the sdk and add new sdk in my system and then add in framework but still I'm getting same problem.
I stuck ! help me.

Comment: did u set path in FrameworksearchPaths like "/users/vani/documents/FacebookSDK"

Answer (score 4):

Fo to your project-> Build Phases -> Open Link Binary with Phases & delete Facebook SDK & Add again.

[image: Then go to your project-> Build Settings -> Framework Search Path -> Just drag & drop your Proj to dilough Box.It will take path automatically]

Now Clean & Build your Project.It will work.

Be sure that Facebook SDK is placed inside your project folder

Answer (score 1):

import the FaceBookSDK framework into yourClass and AppDelegate Also

Go to "Build Settings" in Xcode, and under "Search Paths" there is a "Framework Search Paths" item. Double-click it and paste the file path like "/Users/Vani/Documents/FaceBookSDK/"

Be aware this setting exists both under 'Project' and 'Target', so paste it in both places.

Clean project and build. This time it should work.

I hope it works

Comment: I'd recommend using the variable $PROJECT_DIR/Frameworks 
 that way it should work on other machines